# Debug mode c# application

Tags: c#, debugging, release

I'm wondering what happens when I build a WF Application when it's in debug mode and when it's in release mode.

Let's assume I have built a WFA in Release mode. Will the code between

```
#if DEBUG
...code...
#endif
```

be built in the resulting .exe file? I'm asking this because in Debug mode I have some confidential information which I would prefer to keep secret. I don't want anybody reverse-engineering my app to find that information.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check msdn : [#if (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Preprocess statment used by C# compiler. When the C# compiler encounters an #if directive, followed eventually by an #endif directive, it will compile the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined.

So this means that if you build your project in `Release` mode `debug` sysmbol is not defined so the code between that is not get executed and not part of the release build.

Answer (score 3):

No when you build in `release` the content of all blocks like: `#if DEBUG` will not be included in the resulting code. This is by design.

Comment: i just correct one point its not by desing but its how C# compiler works because preprocessing directives used by compiler.... but its +1 from my side

Answer (score 3):

It will not be part of compiled application, will be skipped by the compiler. You can verify it in i.e. [.net reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) (if you would like make sure and see for yourself )